# Autofac: Open generics and base interfaces

Tags: autofac, open-generics

Given the following interfaces and classes, is there a way in Autofac to

- Register a `Provider<T>` for all classes that have a `ProviderAttribute`, with `T` being the type of such a class (Think registering open generics and resolving them with Autofac's `MakeGenericType()`)
- Inject these registered providers as, drum roll, `IEnumerable<IProviderBase>` into the constructor of other classes

Overview:

```
public class ProviderAttribute : Attribute { }

public interface IProviderBase
{
    Type Type { get; }
}

public interface IProvider<T> : IProviderBase
{
    DoSomething(T t);
}

public class Provider<T> : IProvider<T>
{
    public Type Type
    {
        get { return typeof (T); }
    }

    public DoSomething(T t)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a crude solution:

```
var types = GetProviderTypes();

foreach (var type in types)
{
    var t = typeof (Provider<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    builder.RegisterType(t).As<IProviderBase>();
}
```